# Como solucionar erro "cannot coerce class ""group"" to a data.frame"

Tags: r, data.frame

Ao rodar o `script` abaixo, especificamente na parte de **reprodução** dos `data.frames` foi retornado o erro:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE,
>   stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""group"" to a data.frame

Procurei na internet e não consegui reproduzir as sugestões para o meu caso, alguém me indica um caminho?

```
setwd("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FDMZfWrEjsvleVdNOUiPh8REGjvQHKQx")
rend <- read.table('IVCM.txt', header = TRUE, sep="\t")
rend <- transform(rend, Fungicidas=factor(Fungicidas), Doses=factor(Doses), Rep=factor(Rep))
str(rend)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# desdobrando a interação em testes de Tukey

require(agricolae)
require(plyr)

KinA <- sapply(levels(rend$Doses), simplify=FALSE,
               function(Doses){
                 with(subset(rend, Doses==Doses),
                      HSD.test(IVCM, Fungicidas,
                               DFerror=df.residual(m0),
                               MSerror=deviance(m0)/df.residual(m0)))
               })

KinA <- llply(KinA, NULL)
KinA$M <- gsub(" ", "", KinA$M, fixed=TRUE)
KinA$trt <- as.factor(as.numeric(as.character(KinA$trt)))
str(KinA)

AinK <- sapply(levels(rend$Fungicidas), simplify=FALSE,
               function(Fungicidas){
                 with(subset(rend, Fungicidas==Fungicidas),
                      HSD.test(IVCM, Doses,
                               DFerror=df.residual(m0),
                               MSerror=deviance(m0)/df.residual(m0)))
               })

AinK <- llply(AinK, NULL)
AinK$M <- toupper(gsub(" ", "", AinK$M, fixed=TRUE))
AinK$trt <- as.factor(as.numeric(as.character(AinK$trt)))
str(AinK)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# combinando os data.frames para obter o gráfico e a tabela

KinA$comb <- paste(KinA$trt, KinA$.id)
AinK$comb <- paste(AinK$.id, AinK$trt)
desd <- merge(KinA, AinK, by=c("comb","comb"))
desd$let <- with(desd, paste(M.y, M.x, sep=""))
desd <- desd[,c("trt.x","trt.y","means.x","let")]
names(desd) <- c("Fungicidas","Doses","means","let")
str(desd)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: O link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JdgsnJn5VrkL8j1BsfWzqYW9fMGXND6U leva para uma tabela que não tem as colunas que são esperadas pelo script. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Link atualizado @DanielFalbel. Esse é o arquivo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FDMZfWrEjsvleVdNOUiPh8REGjvQHKQx

Comment: @FabianoFrança Dá erro: `Error in deviance(m0) : objeto 'm0' não encontrado`.

Comment: @FabianoFrança Se ajustar um modelo linear tal como `m0 <- lm(IVCM ~ Fungicidas + Doses, rend)` dá o seu erro e o problema é que `merge` é para objetos de classe `"data.frame"` e tanto `class(KinA)` como `class(AinK)` são `[1] "list"`. Além disso, não vejo motivo para correr `KinA <- llply(KinA, NULL)` e o `gsub` da linha seguinte e o mesmo para `llply(AinK, etc)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas foi feito o ajuste do modelo e checagem, que é  `m0 <- aov(IVCM~Rep+Doses*Fungicidas, data=rend)
summary(m0)
par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(m0); layout(1)`. Mesmo assim, o erro persiste.

Comment: @FabianoFrança Obrigado pela resposta. Mas veja no meu segundo comentário que o erro principal não vem do modelo, mas dos valores de `HSD.test` que estão em `KinA` e em `AinK`, mais exatamente, do tipo de dados (`"list"`) que `HSD.test` produz. A função `merge` **não aceita** listas.

Comment: @RuiBarradas realmente, obrigado pelas dicas. Tentarei outra forma de correr a estatística. Grato!